# What wall material can be installed behind a standing stove?

Tags: walls, fireplace, fire-hazard, woodstove

There used to be wood paneling behind the standing stove but the old owners at some point removed it in lieu of the distaster you see in the picture. Is there something that I can put that will blend with the rest of the wood paneling well? We are painting the wood white so if there is a fire rated drywall or something like this that would be great.

[image]

Further strange discovery, the cement backerboard (painted white for some reason) had an artificial gap between it and the drywall behind it using two large nuts.

[image]

As far as I understand, if a noncombustible material is used on the wall (even screwed directly in the studs) and the stove is 10'' away from the wall then it is according to code. Is this correct?

Comment: That looks a lot like what was code legal in the 70's but a crappie job. Depending on the stove we usually put 2x4's up then cement or wonder board from hearth level to ceiling and tiled, some where were flat some were curved but I can tell you if done correctly it will last a life time. My moms house has a ? Fisher wood stove looking at the top profile if I remember correctly that has been in place since the early 70's that looks as good today as it did when dad did it. I don't think this stove is 10" away from the tile but do know it was done to code at the time as it sold lots of installs.

Comment: Thank you Ed, this helps a lot. So basically what you are saying just to make sure I understand correctly, I need to remove the panel and drywall so that the fiberglass and studs are exposed. Then build the wall outward using 2x4's and install something like DUROCK on top, and, then tile over to make everything flush. My question is, can I skip using the 2x4's or is the air gap necessary? I was just thinking placing DUROCK directly on the studs but I want to make sure it will be safe.

Comment: I used to do this in the 70's & 80's when my dads company installed wood stoves, the air gap was the important part, I don't know if it would still be code, the last one I did was almost 20 years ago for my home at the time but it did pass inspection, I have one in my current home but it is only a half wall as it is a pellet stove and you can touch the sides of the stove when running the inspector only asked about the air intake on that one.